# TYPO3 extbase insert fe_user in database of my plugin

Tags: model, dns, typo3

I try to insert fe_user ID in database table of my plugin. Here is what I tried but without success.

**Controller:**

```
public function createAction(\Pssst\Pscommunity\Domain\Model\Article $newArticle) {
    $newArticle->setFuID((int) $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->user['uid']);
    $this->articleRepository->add($newArticle);
    $this->redirect('list');
}
```

**Model:**

```
/**
 * fuID
 *
 * @var int
 */
protected $fuID = '';

 /**
 * Returns the fuID
 *
 * @return int $fuID
 */
public function geFuID() {
    return $this->fuID;
}

/**
 * Sets the fuID
 *
 * @param int $fuID
 * @return void
 */
public function setFuID($fuID) {
    $this->fuID = $fuID;
}
```

**ext_tables.php**

fuID int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,

Please, anybody knows what I do wrong here?

Comment: The mapping from the model property to the database table field is based on conventions (but can be configured), and you didn't use the convention. Try to name the database field `fu_i_d` (insert an underscore before each capital letter and convert the capital letter to lower case), or better: rename the model property to `fuId` and the table field to `fu_id`. Or even better: Use a proper relation, so you can handle the users using extbase.

Answer (score 0):

I think you solution is bad. Much better would be relation to fe_user object. Extbase has a model of fe_user object, in this case your field should not be type int but typed as this object.

but if you need your sample to work than map the field in typoscript (use the mapping setting). You have wrong name convention and this might be a problem that is why mapping over typoscript (object fielt to table field) is a "must" in your case

Comment: Thank you both. The cause might be the name convention also, but I also tried with a simplified name, for example 'userid', but it still didn't work. So, another problem was somewhere else. I didn't want to waste the time to fix it, and I just created new extension, via extension builder, and solved my problem.

Comment: could you post an example of how to map the field in typoscript "(use the mapping settings)"? It would be usefull to other also.

Comment: I think there is nothing wrong with using setting the ID. Realtionmapping based on that IDs so Extbase will resolve this properly anyway. Injecting the Extbase FeUserRepository to load an feUser Object just to set the ID anyway is a bit overhead I think. But as mentioned already PLZ USE NAMING CONVENTIONS!! and use the custom mapping just in cases where there is no way to rename the property or database-field.